# edited my php.ini, but still the phpmyadmin wont increase file size upload

Tags: php, mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I am trying to increase my upload filesize limit to import an sql file into phpmyadmin.

I have checked the phpinfo and ensured I am modifying the correct php.ini file and adjusted these settings on it:

```
memory_limit = 200M
post_max_size = 200M    
upload_max_filesize = 150M
```

Have restarted Mamp several times, but still no affect made the file size limit on phpmyadmin.

This is a local build, so no shared hosting to worry about.

By the way I am using MAMP Pro, think that maybe causing a conflict

Thanks a lot for any suggestions

Comment: Are you able to access or modifying the mysql database?

Comment: Are you loading the correct php.ini?  What is the `Loaded Configuration File` and `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` in `phpinfo();` ?

Comment: Check for other server config files.

Comment: @Altmish yes I am able to modify my database

Comment: @Glavić the "Loaded Configuration File" indentifies the path to my php.ini file I altered. "Scan this dir for additional .ini files" is set to "(none)"

Comment: @user2174484: ok, but what does `phpinfo()` say for values your are setting?

Comment: @Glavić - "memory_limit = 128M", "post_max_size = 32M", "upload_max_filesize = 32M"... so I guess php also is not seeing the changes

Comment: I just noticed my phpinfo() is looking for my php.ini file inside a "conf" dir at the end of the path when it should be looking in just "php5.5.10" for the php.ini. how can I adjust this?

Comment: How does deleting all php.ini files accept one cause php to not look for php.ini in a currently non-existent folder? I went and copied the php.ini I intend for it to use and put into a conf directory I created. This still had no effect after restart of mamp

Comment: Discovered the problem, using MAMP Pro, editing the php.ini is not done through the file directly but through the menu system in the application to open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust the php.ini file in Mamp Pro, you need to open it through the menu system in the application itself, not through the file directory.

File -> Edit Template -> PHP -> php 5.5.10 php.ini

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the case in your php.ini file, but don't forget the semicolon. If that doesn't work try this link http://phptale.com/how-to-increase-php-memory-limit/

```
memory_limit = 128M ;
```

Comment: There is no need for semicolon in php.ini

Comment: in php.ini the semi-colon denotes a comment